# Can't get python subprocess.Popen() to start another python script in the background

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am in a bit of a pickle here. I have a python script (gather.py) that gathers information from an .xml file and uploads it into a database on a infinite loop that sleeps for 60sec; btw all of this is local. I am using Flask to run a webpage that will later pull information from the database, but at the moment all it does is display a sample page (main.py). I want to run main.py as for it to start gather.py as background process that won't prevent Flask from starting, I tried importing gather.py but it halts the process (indefinitely) and Flask won't start. After Googling for a while it seems that the best option is to use a task queue (Celery) and a message-broker (RabbitMQ) to take care of this. This is fine if the application were to do a lot of stuff in the background, but I only need it to do 1 or 2 things. So I did more digging and found posts stating that `subprocess.Popen()` could do the job. I tried using it and I don't think it failed, since it didn't raise any errors, but the database is empty. I confirmed that both gather.py and main.py work independently. I tried running the following code in IDLE:

`subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'path\to\gather.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

and got this in return:

`<subprocess.Popen object at 0x049A1CF0>`

Now, I don't know what this means, I tried using `.value` and `.attrib` but understandably I get this:

`AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'value'`
and
`AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'attrib'`

Then I read on a StackOverflow post that `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` would cause the program to halt so, in a 'just in case' moment, I ran:

`subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'path\to\gather.py'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

and got this in return:

`<subprocess.Popen object at 0x034A77D0>`

Through all this process the database tables have remained empty. I am new to the `subprocess` module but all this checks and I can't figure out why it is not running gather.py. Is it because it has an infinite loop?? If there is a better option pls let me know.

Python version: 3.4.4

PS. IDK if it'll matter but I am running a portable version of Python (PortableApps) on a Windows 10 PC. This is why I included `sys.executable` inside `subprocess.Popen()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You may want to add to your question some info on which platform (Linux, Windows) you are using

Comment: Did you print the result of `sys.executable' to see what is in variable? If python is unable to get the path, sys.executable will return None or empty string.

Comment: André Ginklings, I did printed the ```sys.executable``` value and it pointed to python. Here's the output: 
```sys.executable``` 
                             
                 ```'G:\\PortableApps\\WinPythonPortable\\App\\WinPython\\python-3.4.4\\python.exe'
```

Comment: If you open a command prompt (cmd.exe) and execute `G:\PortableApps\WinPythonPortable\App\WinPython\python-3.4.4\python.exe path\to\gather.py` the script works?

Comment: André Ginklings, yup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 (all in python script):
Try to use Thread and Queue.

I do this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import json

from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time


def task(q):
    q.put(0)
    t = time.time()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        q.put(time.time() - t)
        

queue = Queue()
worker = Thread(target=task, args=(queue,))
worker.start()

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def message_from_queue():
    msg = "Running: calculate %f seconds" % queue.get()
    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

If you run this code each access to '/' get a value calculate in `task` in background. Maybe you need to block until the task get a value, but it isnt enough information in the question. Of course you need to refactor your gather.py to pass a queue for it.

Solution 2 (using a system script):

For windows, create a .bat file and run both script from there:

```
@echo off
start python 'path\to\gather.py'
set FLASK_APP=app.py
flask run
```

This will run gather.py and after start the flask server. If you use `start /min python 'path\to\gather.py'` the gather will run in minimized mode.

Comment: André Ginklings, thanks for the reply. I did think of threading but was unable to get it to work. It must have been that I didn't use the ```Queue``` module. Either way I desisted because I need gather.py to run in the background independently of main.py. When I put this application into production gather.py should be constantly running. I wanted to see if I could start it from python to then add a function to check if it was running and to run it if it wasn't. BTW, what extra information should I add to the post??

Comment: What do you want with gather.py? This is a background process, ok. But when is this running? Only when the Flask app is running too? Always running? If you need to run this in main.py from the flask app, the Popen should work and Thread too. If you need gatter.py execute as a service, independent of the Flask app is running or no, you just need to execute it as system service (in this way you should informe what is your system). If you manally run gather .py from terminal and run the Flask app, it works as you want?

Comment: André Ginklings I want to start both from a single call. It [gather.py] should be running at all times but in case of a power outage I want to be able to just run one script and everything goes from there. I want to run only 1 file not two independent ones and I am using Windows 10. The server in which this application will be placed into production is also a Windows environment. I know I could use something like NSSM to run gather.py as a service but that will make it OS dependent and I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I update my question using a windows batch script.

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.Popen will not work in opening a python program because it recognizes python as a file and not a executable. Subprocess.Popen can only open .exe files and nothing other than that.
You can use:

```
os.system('python_file_path.py')
```

but it won't be a background process(depends on your script)

Comment: Popen dont open only executables. This run system commands too and scripts. indeed, Popen can run every command that you can run in a terminal (on windows, mac, linux). And you are assuming that he is Windows system.